# Where does the protons and electrons go in this redox reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

[image]

In the above oxidation reaction, does the 2 protons and electrons released get accepted by oxygen molecules? If not, where do they go?

Appreciate all answers :)

Comment: Yes, they get accepted by oxygen molecule (or any other oxidant, for that matter). Where else could they go, really?

Comment: Even the protons? Because I learnt that only electrons are exchanged between molecules in a redox reaction.

Comment: It depends on the oxidant.

Comment: In my school's experiment, orange juice is exposed to oxygen. So oxygen?

Comment: That's right.$\;$

Comment: So oxygen does accept the 2 protons?

Comment: Yes, and the electrons too. That's how it turns into H2O.

Comment: See this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/116242/79678