# Iodometric Titration: Would iodine react with sucrose as well?

Tags: organic-chemistry, titration

I'm currently planning to do a lab experiment about the effect of sugar addition (sucrose) to orange juice on Vitamin C (ascorbic acid), also finding the degradation rate and activation energy required. To measure ascorbic acid concentration, I am going to use iodometric titration but I am wondering if the addition of sucrose would affect the results as I am not sure if iodine could also react with sucrose, not just ascorbic acid, so that the results do not show the correct concentration of ascorbic acid in the juice. If that is the case, is there any better method to measure just the ascorbic acid content? I am currently a high school student and may not be familiar with some hard concepts, so please be mindful.

Comment: Did you mean, ...orange juice **or** vitamin C, instead of **on**?

Comment: i meant the effect of sugar addition on vitamin c content in the orange juice cuz I'm going to make a homemade juice and add different amounts of sugar to see how vitamin c content in each differ

Comment: This is a fairly common undergraduate experiment. The sucrose will not do anything and it will not interfere with the ascorbic acid determination. See here for more information: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/116238/79678